# GitKraken Snap - Sign in with Github button not working

Tags: 18.04, snap, xdg-open

I installed the latest GitKraken snap (4.1.1) from Ubuntu Software on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04.01. When I run it and try to sign in with Github nothing happens, after some seconds a message appears in the bottom part of the form:

> The access token provided is invalid

When I start it from the terminal, the error message I get after clicking on the *Sign in with Github* button is:

> /usr/bin/xdg-open: 2: exec: snapctl: not found

The expected behavior is that GitKraken opens the default browser and a page where you can authenticate using Github. This problem happens on three different PCs, all running Ubuntu 18.04.01.

Other (maybe useful) info:

> Kernel: 4.15.0-39-generic
>
> `snapd` version: 2.34.2+18.04

I would appreciate some advice on how to solve this particular problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I signed into Github and revoked all open sessions and revoked the Authorized Oauth Apps and then the connect to github button in Gitkraken started working again.

Revoke Access to GitKraken in Github:

1. Settings

   [image]
2. Applications

   [image]
3. Authorized Apps

   [image]
4. Revoke Access GitKraken

   [image]

Comment: Welcome to askUbuntu! where does one go on github to revoke sessions? this looks like a working answer that could be made great with some more info or screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the exact same problem and tried [Ryan Swaby's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1099323/742924) but still didn't work, so I just:

- Installed Chrome
- Uninstalled GitKraken and installed it form Ubuntu Software

Not sure if Chrome was necessary and I still don't know why it wouldn't work in the first place, but now it's running fine